# Trouble with viewport and centering on iPhone & iPad safari

Tags: iphone, ipad, safari

I'm trying to help fix a friend's webpage. She paid a guy $800 to make a site for her, and as soon as it went up, he bounced without making it compatible with `iOS Safari` *(as he had promised)*. She can't get a hold of this guy and it's months later. So anyway, I'm trying to help her out. [www.avasassi.com](http://www.avasassi.com)

---

- **I tried to fix the viewport tag**

  - The entire display showed up too large on iOS safari
  - You couldn't properly zoom out to view the page
  - She wants it to load up correctly, and centered on the initial load up
  - Every page has this issue
  - I've only tweaked index.hmtl and projects.html so far

The [original viewport tag](http://www.avasassi.com/spicemates.html) was...

```
<meta content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=1;" name="viewport">
```

I tried tweaking it to [this viewport tag](http://www.avasassi.com/projects.html) with mediocre results

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale = 0.5" />
```

---

- **Next the projects page *(projects.html)***

  - shows the individual images centered in firefox and chrome, but on safari on iPhone
  - it's off center, and somehow cuts the orange bar short so that it doesn't span the whole page
  - the images aren't centered with the header

Here's the code for the project page's images...

```
<section id="frame">
<div class="row1 cbox"><a class="samlink" href="saltysam.html"></a></div>
<div class="row2 cbox"><a class="spicelink" href="spicemates.html"></a></div>
<div class="row3 cbox"><a class="khloelink" href="khloe.html"></a></div>
<div class="row4 cbox"><a class="simonlink" href="simon.html"></a></div>
<div class="row5 cbox"><a class="thrivelink" href="thrive.html"></a></div>
</section>
```

CSS

```
#frame {
width: 450px;
height: 1850px;
margin: 0 auto;
position: relative;
display: block;
```

&

```
.cbox {
position: absolute;
overflow: hidden;
opacity: 1.0;
filter: alpha(opacity=100);
width: 450px;
margin: 0 auto;
```

---

**Any and all help is gladly appreciated. Cheers.**